# Python object.__new__() takes no parameters in main()

Tags: python, parameters

I try to execute some python code but i face a problem with passing the parameters.
My python code is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

class Sim(object):

    def print_db_parameters(self):
         print "Host = %s" %self.host
         print "User = %s" %self.user
         print "Password = %s" %self.password
         print "Database = %s" %self.database

def main():
    host = "localhost"
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
    database = "sim"
    sim_test = Sim(host,user,password,database)
    sim_test.print_db_parameters()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i run it, i receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sim.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()   
  File "Sim.py", line 17, in main
    sim_test = Sim(host,user,password,database)
  TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please show the actual error and the full traceback, rather than only the part of the traceback preceding the error.

Comment: TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters

Comment: The code you posted cannot produce the error message you posted, as you don't have a `SimVAX` class. Please post the actual code you are using and an error message that makes sense in the context of that code.

Comment: The code in the traceback is not the same as in the main() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing parameters to a class constructor

```
sim_test = Sim(host,user,password,database)
```

But not accepting them. You must create an `__init__` method to deal with them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

class Sim(object):
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):  #New method!!
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.database = database

    def print_db_parameters(self):
         print "Host = %s" %self.host
         print "User = %s" %self.user
         print "Password = %s" %self.password
         print "Database = %s" %self.database

def main():
    host = "localhost"
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
    database = "ARISTEIA_vax"
    sim_test = Sim(host,user,password,database)
    sim_test.print_db_parameters()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an `__init__` method for your class, but you're passing parameters to the constructor. You should create an `__init__` method that accepts parameters.

Answer (score 1):

to follow up mipadi with example:  It would probably be very helpful to read some tutorials on object oriented programming in python http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

```
class Sim(object):

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
       self.host = host
       self.user = user
       self.password = password
       self.database = database

    def print_db_parameters(self):
         print "Host = %s" %self.host
         print "User = %s" %self.user
         print "Password = %s" %self.password
         print "Database = %s" %self.database
```